# How to run or compile DirectX 10 application in windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, directx-10

Please, help.
Does anyone know how to compile DirectX10 application for windows XP? I know microsoft didn't make support for directx 10 in windows XP, but I saw some hack libraries to use DirectX 10 in windows XP and in doesn't work for me. Is there really right way to run DirectX 10 applications for windows XP?

Comment: Windows XP is fully out of support as of April 8, 2014 and is now [end-of-life](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/end-support-help). DirectX 9.0c is the last version of DirectX supported by Windows XP. Visual Studio 202 or later will not install on Windows XP as they require Windows 7 SP1 or later. You can still target Windows XP with VS 2012 Update 1, VS 2013, or VS 2015 but the xp Platform Toolset uses the Windows 7.1A SDK. See [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/11/26/visual-studio-2012-update-1.aspx) for some notes on DirectX development for Windows XP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have effectively answered your own question.

There is no

> really right way to run DirectX 10 [on] windows XP

As [DirectX FAQ - Will DirectX 10 be available for Windows XP?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416788%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Will_DirectX_10_be_available_for_Windows_XP) points out DirectX 10 relies on both:

- new system calls that do not exist in Windows XP

and

- code changes to support a new driver mode created for newer versions of Windows

Existing DirectX 10 [programs that are run on a Windows XP system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectX#DirectX_10)

> simply resort to using the code from DirectX 9.0c

There are some

> hack libraries to use DirectX 10 in windows XP

[TechMixer - Download DirectX 10 for Windows XP](http://www.techmixer.com/download-directx-10-for-windows-xp/)

but they may not work.